# Xolvio/meteor-cucumber: get this.userId when logged in

Tags: meteor, cucumberjs

when using xxx shouldnt my fixture methods be aware of `this.userId` if I am logged in?

```
'userId': function () {
      console.log("#################");
      console.log("################# USERID: ", this.userId);
      console.log("#################");
    }
```

This always prints `null` when called from a step definition.

Comment: Please add the code around this in order to understand the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are calling this from a step definition using `this.server.call` you are making a server to server connection therefore you won't be logged in.

You need to use the client to make a call to be authenticated:

```
this.client.executeAsync(function() {
  Meteor.call('userId') // this will be sent from the client
});
```